# Graphql mutation for a column of type UUID[]

Tags: postgresql, uuid, graphql, postgraphql

I'm using a postgraphql autogenerated mutation to create a row with graphql in a in a postgres table that has a column of datatype UUID[].

However, there doesn't seem to be a way to save this UUID[] data with graphql? Is this a datatype that graphql doesn't account for or am I wrongly forming the array?

When I go to create the row in graphiql:

```
mutation {
  createJob(
    input: {
      user_ids: ["5b7323ac-e235-4edb-bbf9-97495d9a42a1"], 
      instructions: "Job Instructions", 
      publishedDate: "2017-06-07"}
   }
 )
}
```

I get the following error:

```
"message": "column \"user_ids\" is of type uuid[] but expression is of type text[]"
```

Is a UUID technically not stored like text? I've tried different ways of forming the the UUID array but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 3):

You can *probably* have a workaround to this problem by creating an *implicit cast*:

```
CREATE CAST (text[] AS uuid[])
    WITH INOUT
    AS IMPLICIT ;
```

PostgreSQL will automatically do the conversion from `text[]` to `uuid[]`; which just seems that is the needed step.

---

NOTE: The above code must be executed from "the owner of type uuid[] or text[]", which usually means: `postgres` or the database owner.

---

To check that it works, you may just do:

```
CREATE TABLE t
(
   ids uuid[]
) ;

INSERT INTO t 
    (ids)
VALUES
    (ARRAY['5b7323ac-e235-4edb-bbf9-97495d9a42a1','5b7323ac-e235-4edb-bbf9-97495d9a42a2']),
    (ARRAY['6b7323ac-e235-4edb-bbf9-97495d9a42a1']) ;
```

... and then, test it with `GraphQL`

Comment: This worked for me in GraphQL / PostgreSQL. Thanks a lot Joanolo

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in PostGraphQL; it's been fixed in version 4 (which has not been released yet, but you can install via `npm install postgraphql@next`)

More information: https://github.com/postgraphql/postgraphql/issues/516